# Get a message's ID using Gmail API from a list so it can be used later in automation

Tags: java, arraylist, automation, gmail-api

I currently have a quick block of code that will sort through the automation's Gmail account to find the latest message, and list its ID. How exactly can I save that ID to a separate string, so it can be used later on to get the message for comparison. Am I missing a specific line of code, or should I rewrite it in some way? Thanks.

Create a list of the messages using a query. It's going to print the ID of each message.

```
private List<Message> listMessage(Gmail service,
                                  String query) throws IOException {
    ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list("me").setQ(query).execute();

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    while (response.getMessages() != null) {
        messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
        if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
            String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
            response = service.users().messages().list("me").setQ(query)
                    .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(messages.isEmpty()) {
        listMessage(service, query);
    }
    for (Message message : messages) { //This is going to print the ID of each message.
        System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
    }
    return messages;
}
```

This is going to find the latest one.

```
public void listGmailEmail() {
    long unixTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    try {
        listMessage(service, "after: " + unixTime);

    } catch (IOException ignored) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.

1. Get list of messages
2. Turn the list into a JSON
3. Create a method to get the message
4. Filter the JSON to get the message ID
5. Apply the message ID to the new method
6. Get the message

   ```
   private List<Message> getMessageID(Gmail service,
                                 String query) throws IOException {
   ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list("me").setQ(query).execute();

   List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
   while (response.getMessages() != null) {
       messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
       if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
           String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
           response = service.users().messages().list("me").setQ(query)
                   .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
       } else {
           break;
       }
   }
   if(messages.isEmpty()) {
       getMessageID(service, query);
   }
   messageID = gson.toJson(messages);

   return messages;
   }

   private Message getEmail(Gmail service, String userId, String messageId)
       throws IOException {
   Message message = service.users().messages().get(userId, messageId).execute();

   email = message.toString();

   return message;
   }

   public void getGmailEmail() {
   try {
       getMessageID(service, "after: " + unixTime);
       messageID = messageID.split("\",")[0].substring(8);
       getEmail(service,"me", messageID);
       System.out.println("Email received");
       emailOrThread = email;
   } catch (IOException ignored) { }
   }
   ```